# Angular 2 : How to let *ngIf use value from array of *ngFor which includes it?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i am new to angular 2 and ionic , so i will try to make it short:

```
 <ion-card class="acc-page-card" *ngFor="let account of accounts">
   <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    <ion-item (click)="GoTo('AccountPage')">
        <div class="acc-img" item-left>
            <img src="{{account.img}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="acc-details">
            <span class="name">{{account.title}}</span>
            <span class="title">{{account.link}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="acc-icons" item-right>
            <i *ngIf="valueFromArray" class="icomoon-Add-user-icon"></i>
            <i *ngIf="valueFromArray" class="icomoon-Favorites-icon"></i>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
```

where 'valueFromArray' is the value I want to get from the array i am looping 
i tried:

```
<i *ngIf="{{account.isFriend}}" class="icomoon-Add-user-icon active-icon"></i>
```

and it was so wrong.
so, how to use value from array i am looping in a situation like this?
sorry for my bad English .

Comment: Can you show us your array structure with data and specify which value you want to use in `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just access it like you would any other variable:

```
<i *ngIf="account.isFriend" class="icomoon-Add-user-icon active-icon"></i>
```

Also a few lines further up the img tag should be:

```
        <img [src]="account.img" alt="">
```

Don't use the interpolation `{{...}}` inside attributes, you only need that in the content text. For attribute values like `src` you should use the input property binding `[attribute]=value`

Answer (score 2):

try with *ngIf="account.isFriend"

```
<i *ngIf="account.isFriend" class="icomoon-Add-user-icon active-icon"></i>
```